# How to search SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table `Registration` with name and datetime, I want to search the data with datetime which is less then `datetime.now`.

```
SqlDataAdapter cs = 
    new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Registration where Date > DateTime.now")
```

I want that datetime is less then today.

Comment: You need to learn ADO.Net, What have you tried? where have you looked?  Here is the msdn page :- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577376(v=bts.20).aspx

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2209321/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Three---Searching-for-Particular-Date-Values-and-Ranges.htm

Comment: You need a SqlCommand with parameters : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Comment: She does not need to use `SqlCommand` with parameters, she can do it directly in the constructor for the `SqlDataAdapter`.

Answer (score 4):

The T-SQL built-in function [`getdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) returns the current server date/time.

Therefore your query should be, `SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE [Date] < getdate()`.

Using this in your code would be:

```
SqlDataAdapter cs = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Registration where [Date] < getdate()")
```

Comment: the question say less then datetime.now

Comment: @IswantoSan Yeah, bad copy-paste. Thanks

Comment: But Dear Table Columen DataType is DateTime not only date??

Comment: @SaimaMaheen `getdate()` contains the date and time. Look at the linked documentation.

Comment: Dear But if i want manual enter date in textbox or selection date from monthcalender1 what is code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQL `GETDATE()` to do this:

```
SqlDataAdapter cs = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Registration where Date < GETDATE()")
```

Comment: But Dear Table Columen DataType is DateTime not only date??

Comment: Dear But if i want manual enter date in textbox or selection date from monthcalender1 what is code?

Answer (score 2):

Use [GETDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) to get current date in your query.

```
SqlDataAdapter cs = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Registration where Date < GETDATE()");
```

Comment: But Dear Table Columen DataType is DateTime not only date??

Answer (score 1):

This may work...  if you want to use .NET DateTime, that will be the date of the local system.

```
     SqlDataAdapter cs = new SqlDataAdapter(
           "SELECT * FROM [Registration] 
            WHERE [Date] < '" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() +"';");

     //output: SELECT * FROM [Registration] WHERE [Date] < '2/22/2013';
```

It is going to depend upon the data type of the [date] column, if it is string or datetime or something else.  If it is YYYYmmdd, then you can manipluate the DateTime.Now output to match.

Comment: Dear But if i want manual enter date in textbox or selection date from monthcalender1 what is code?

Comment: if using a text box, collect and DateTime.TryParse() the entered text.  if you are using a calendar control, it should have a means to export the date in whatever format you need it in.  Place the data-values in the string in place of 'DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()'

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple..

if you want to use sql current datetime use 
SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE [Date] < getdate()

and if you want your application current datetime use

"SELECT * FROM Registration WHERE [Date] < '+Datetime.Now.Tostring() +'"

Also try to use parameterized query if you want second option.